# Understanding unprovable halting, model theory, and (in)completeness

Tags: halting-problem, first-order-logic

I know computability, but not model theory and logic, so this question may be naive or confused in that respect.

A [blog post of Scott Aaronson](https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=2725) mentions a Turing Machine $M^*$ such that the statement P:

\begin{align} &\text{$M^*$ runs forever on a blank tape} & (P) \end{align}

can be proven in ZFC+large cardinal assumption, but P cannot be proven in ZFC.

My understanding is that by Godel's completeness theorem, P is provable in ZFC if and only if P is true in every model of ZFC.

So it seems to follow that there are models of ZFC in which P is false, i.e. models where $M^*$ halts when run on a blank tape. **Q1: is this correct?**

However, if $M^*$ halts on a blank tape, then the trace of the execution provides a proof that $M^*$ halts, which seems like it should be a valid proof that $M^*$ halts in all of ZFC, [see this question.](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21374/turing-machines-whose-termination-is-unprovable) So it seems like we've reached a contradiction. **Q2: can you resolve my confusion?**

Comment: The problem is that, in a universe where $M^*$ halts, the time it takes $M^*$ to halt will be "nonstandard" (= look finite from the perspective of the model but in reality not make sense). The corresponding execution trace will also be not-actually-finitary. ([This old MSE answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660650/why-is-the-status-of-the-period-in-laver-tables-not-settled/3660682#3660682) is related.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber that is like the coolest thing ever. I'd love to get some sense of what running turing machine in such a universe actually means, especially given that it's the "same" TM. But I guess I need to understand nonstandard numbers first.